# libjpeg with image_optim gem on Heroku Cedar Stack (Ruby buildpack)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I'm trying to get the [image_optim](https://github.com/toy/image_optim) gem to work with a Rails 4 app on Heroku's Cedar stack to optimize png/gif/jpeg images.

I threw the required binaries (`advpng`, `gifsicle`, `jpegoptim`, `jpegtran`, `optipng`, `pngcrush`, `pngout`) into `/bin` and set `ENV['PATH'] = "#{Rails.root}/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"` in an initializer. This works for gifs and pngs, but I'm running into problems with jpegs.

In the rails console I get:

`` irb(main):001:0> `jpegoptim` ``

`jpegoptim: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How should I go about installing `libjpeg` on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to deploy binaries to Heroku is to use buildpacks:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Use this one if you want to package up multiple binaries:
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

There are a number of buildpacks already created for various binaries, but none for the ones you have listed.

Comment: I just created a buildpack with image_optim binaries for Heroku, see : https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack

Answer (score 0):

I have created a gem that allows you to run image_optim on heroku:

https://github.com/mooktakim/image_optim_bin

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for this: [Heroku Image-Optim Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/sensedata/image-optim-buildpack)

Or this: https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack